# Bug report submitting

Tags: support

If someone were to find a bug/glitch/feature-request in the website, or the android app, how could it be reported?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: I've seen that page, but only briefly while on a computer. On my phone, I could not find an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Report bugs here, and tag them with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).  Same goes for feature requests; just use [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).  If it specifically relates to the app, add [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app).

Don't forget things like:

- A description of what you're seeing (pictures or a link can help)
- Why it's an anomaly
- If it's a feature request, explain why it'd be a good feature to have

Comment: If its for any/all stack exchange sites, which meta should it go in?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com.  But, I believe that the bug tracker would pick it up on any meta site anyway.

Comment: If the bug is reported, does it ever get adressed? Because in my case, people only started to explain what is happenning, I did not get any answer from mods if it is gonna get fixed...